# Trying to setup first app, but website not playing ball

Tags: android, google-fabric

I'm trying to setup Crashlytics on an existing Android app, which currently uses Firebase, but I'm having problems getting to certain parts of the site.

Going from the documentation page:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/app.html

I click on the "settings" hyperlinks, and instead of taking me through to an organisation settings page, I'm directed to the Crashlytics Summary page: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary

The problem is that I want to setup a new API Key, and the sample code has *A* key in it, but not *MY* key (because I haven't been able to generate one).

How am I able to create a new app and API Key for Crashlytics?

Any help in this direction would be *greatly* appreciated!

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Voting to close this down as it is not related to coding in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If you're logged in at https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary, then the API key present is your actual API key, not a sample key. If you've created a new organization and need to change the organization to get a different key, you can select that here. [image: select that here]